# Implement Instagram like swipe right to view camera

Tags: android, android-viewpager, instagram

Basically this is the structure of my app.

[image]

In Activity, there is a container which hosts fragments and on the bottom there is Bottom Navigation View. I want to implement something like this:

[image]

I know this is possible by using ViewPager but the app is already much complex that I wouldn't want to rewrite all the flows to make whole activity as fragment and then add in ViewPager. Is there any other approach I can take to solve this issue? Anything like drawer layout or similar? Any close possible solution suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Did you get any solution for that? I want to implement same with navigation architecture.

Comment: No mate. ViewPager with fragments seems like the only option

Comment: Yes, I am also implementing it with Viewpager and fragments.

Comment: Then I think it's pretty straightforward. What issue are you facing?